# template specialization for CPPUnit isn't being used

Tags: c++, templates, cppunit, template-specialization

If you've used CPPUnit before, you are probably aware of its `assertion_traits` class that is templatized to handle arbitrary types.  This is what allows it to print the "actual" and "expected" values for non-string types when test cases fail.  I have used this with success several times, but for one specific type it isn't working for me.  Here is a partial declaration for my class, its parent's class, and some non-member operators (the whole thing is huge, plus my company won't let me post it):

```
class _declspec(dllexport) HWDBDateTime
{
public:
    HWDBDateTime();
    HWDBDateTime(const HWDBDateTime& other);

    HWDBDateTime& operator=(const HWDBDateTime& other);

    RWCString asString() const;
    RWCString asString(const char *format, const boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr pZone = STimeZone::GetServerTimeZone()) const;
};

bool _declspec(dllexport) operator==(const HWDBDateTime& dt1, const HWDBDateTime& dt2);
bool _declspec(dllexport) operator!=(const HWDBDateTime& dt1, const HWDBDateTime& dt2);
bool _declspec(dllexport) operator< (const HWDBDateTime& dt1, const HWDBDateTime& dt2);
bool _declspec(dllexport) operator<=(const HWDBDateTime& dt1, const HWDBDateTime& dt2);
bool _declspec(dllexport) operator> (const HWDBDateTime& dt1, const HWDBDateTime& dt2);
bool _declspec(dllexport) operator>=(const HWDBDateTime& dt1, const HWDBDateTime& dt2);

class _declspec(dllexport) STimeStamp : public HWDBDateTime
{
public:

    STimeStamp();

    STimeStamp(const STimeStamp& other);

    STimeStamp(const HWDBDateTime& other);

    explicit STimeStamp(double d);

    STimeStamp& operator=(double d);

    operator double() const;
};
```

And here is my attempt at specializing the CPPUnit assertions class:

```
template <>
struct CppUnit::assertion_traits<STimeStamp>
{  
    static bool equal( STimeStamp x, STimeStamp y )
    {
        return x == y;
    }

    static std::string toString( STimeStamp x )
    {
        return (const char *)x.asString();
    }
};
```

I've tried it passing by value, as seen above, also passing const references, I've tried casting the values inside the functions to `HWDBDateTime` (since that's where the operators and `asString()` methods are defined), nothing seems to help.  I've put it at the top of my test suite's CPP file, and I've put it into a master header file that contains project-wide assertion_traits specializations, such as one for RWCString that works flawlessly.  Somehow, whenever a test case fails, it insists on printing out my time as a floating-point value (presumably a double; a specialization for double is built in to CPPUnit) -- this is why I made sure to include my to/from double conversion operators in the minimized code above.

Is there something inherently wrong with what I'm doing?  Does the specialization need to be present at a certain point in the compilation process, and maybe I just haven't found that point?  Would this mythical point be per-translation-unit or per-project?  I'm using VS2008.

Comment: Did you try to define the template with `const STimeStamp&`? I had a similar problem and that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ type matching is the issue here.

The original type is probably `const STimeStamp&`. When coming from `const T&` most compilers prefers the implicit cast operators (in your case `double`) over creating a copy `T`.

This may be compiler specific...

Comment: apparently I didn't try using the const references AND putting it in my master header file... the combination of the two made it work.  Thanks!